# Are there materials with very high coefficients of static friction but very low coefficients of kinetic friction?

Tags: forces, friction

In my physics class, we use coefficients of static and kinetic friction to calculate the forces of friction. I was wondering if there are materials such that they have very high coefficients of static friction but very low coefficients of kinetic friction.

$$ F _{k} = F _{n} \cdot \mu _{k} $$

$$ F _{sMax} = F _{n} \cdot \mu _{ s} $$

Comment: See https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/amp/friction-coefficients-d_778.html

Comment: Engineers call that "a ratchet", I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a coefficient of friction table found [here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html), it seems that cast iron on cast iron may fit the bill. The coefficient of static friction is 1.1, but the coefficient of kinetic friction is only 0.15 - it takes more than 7 times as much force to initiate movement between cast iron plates as it does it keep them moving at a constant speed. This is the highest ratio I could find between static and kinetic friction coefficients.